# show/hide tr on dropdown selection for a list in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created a list in  sharepoint now in newform I'm trying to hide and show 3 tr alternatively when i click on dropdown value. for eg: I have 3 option in dropdown A, B, C and my tr have ids(A, B, C) click on A only A is there when B only B is there and when C only C is there. same for edit form how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample tested script for a previous thread( I can't remember the link), you could update the script based on your fields' definition.

[SPUtility.js](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/siteassets/sputility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var employeetype = SPUtility.GetSPField('Employee Type');
            var showOrHideField = function () {
                var employeeValue = employeetype.GetValue();
                if (employeeValue == 'Existing Employee') {
                    SPUtility.GetSPField('Employee Name').Show();
                    SPUtility.GetSPField('Employee ID').Show();
                    SPUtility.GetSPField('Candidate Name').Hide();
                }
                else {
                    SPUtility.GetSPField('Employee Name').Hide();
                    SPUtility.GetSPField('Employee ID').Hide();
                    SPUtility.GetSPField('Candidate Name').Show();
                }
            }

            // run at startup (for edit form)
            showOrHideField();
            // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
            $(employeetype.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
        });
```